# Absolute position as per parent's parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 divs as follows:

```
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2">
        <span class="wrapper">test</span>
        <div class="div-3">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

div-1 and div-2 have position: relative.
div-3 has position absolute.
wrapper has position absolute.
I need div-2 to be positioned relatively so that wrapper can be positioned absolutely.
Now what I need is, div-3 must be positioned absolutely in relative to div-1 and not div-2.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can position either with `.div-2` or viewport (`position: fixed`) as a reference. If you know something about position of `.div-2` relative to its positioned parent, then you can position `.div-3` but that's a very particular case :) Edit: what is the constraint that forbids you from moving `.div-3` from a child to a sibling of `.div-2`? Maybe there's a workaround for that problem

Comment: a `position:absolute` div will always stay relative to first parent that has `position:relative` . you need to share the css and also why you need this to work ? what's the end desired result ? maybe we can help you change the logic behind your problem/solution

Comment: you can't change the rules css! for align it, help of left property and top property

Comment: With the existing markup, this is not possible. If you instead explain how you want each part behave, there might be a solution, though with a different way of thinking.

Comment: Can you provide your code please so that we can guess what you want to achieve actually...!

Comment: Are you willing to change your HTML structure? All it would need is an extra `div` around `.wrapper`.

Comment: @WizardCoder will use this work around by adding an extra div around .wrapper. Just wanted to know if anything could be done with the existing markup. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have made .div-3 `position:absolute` , it will be with respect to the parent div which in div-2 in your case. It will get aligned to the top-left corner of it. If you want to make it relative to div-1 try this:

```
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2">
        <span class="wrapper">test</span>
      </div>  
    <div class="div-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

This will make it with relative to div-1. For further understanding of positioning you can go to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)

Answer (score 1):

just set div-2 `position: static`
and div-1 `position: relative`.

that'll work